# Sum over n variables

Tags: programming, function-construction

What is the most painless way to sum over n variables, for example, if the range of summation is $i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \dots < i_n$, where $n$ is an argument of the function in question?

Is there a package for this and more complex summation ranges?

I am not happy with programming loops all the time for this common summation range and if one has a large summation range, one cannot just use a combinat command to generate all subsets of a certain size, if this takes too much memory.

Example:

$$f(n)=\sum_{0 < i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_n < 2n+1} \qquad \prod_{1\le r < s \le n} (i_s-i_r) $$

Comment: So i1, i2 ...in are the ends of the ranges? What about the start of the ranges, always 1? What about variable naming (which variable will get those values)?

Comment: `Boole[]` can sometimes be useful for complicated summations.

Comment: -1: This question is not particularly clear and could use some work (although the subject matter is interesting and welcome!). Can you give a more explicit example of the sums that you're interested in (the site supports LaTeX). Also, please codify all code... Once the question is edited, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Phira, the example sum you have given, which is the (unique) sum of all integer [Vandermonde determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) in a certain range, does it have a closed form? Have you tried to identify the sequence from its first few terms using [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) (or [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/))?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write a few helper functions to help you. The following can probably be streamlined...

```
vars[s_String, n_Integer?Positive] := Table[Symbol[s <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}]
vars[sym_Symbol, num_] := vars[SymbolName[sym], num]

nestedRange[vars_List, min_, max_] /; min <= max := 
 Transpose@{vars, ConstantArray[min, Length[vars]], Append[Rest@vars, max]}

nestedSum[f_, vars:{__Symbol}, min_, max_] /; min <= max := 
 With[{r = Sequence @@ Reverse@nestedRange[vars, min, max]}, Sum[f, r]]
nestedSum[f_, {var:(_String|_Symbol), num_Integer?Positive}, 
 min_, max_] /; min <= max := nestedSum[f, vars[var, num], min, max]
```

Then, for example

```
nestedSum[f[a, b, c], {a, b, c}, 0, Infinity] // TraditionalForm
```

produces [image: screenshot]

A larger sum is

```
In[]:= nestedSum[Total@vars[i, 4], {i, 4}, 1, 20] // Timing
Out[]= {0.016001, 371910}
```

which can be compared with evaluating the same thing using `Boole`

```
In[]:= v = vars[i, 4];
       With[{r = Sequence@@Table[{n, 1, 20}, {n, v}]}, 
            Sum[Boole[LessEqual@@v] Total@v, r]] // Timing
Out[]= {0.056003, 371910}
```

Comment: For your example, isn't there already a simple syntax?  `Sum[f[a, b, c], {c, 0, \[Infinity]}, {b, 0, c}, {a, 0, b}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sure, but now do it for 50 variable sum...

Comment: Okay, I see your point. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another approach. With this solution you would enter the sum in the form `sum[f, a0<a1<a2<=...<an]`, where you can use a mix of `<` and `<=` in the specification of the range of summation.

```
sum[f_, Less[b0_, a__, b1_]] := Sum[f, ##] & @@ 
  Reverse[MapIndexed[{#1[[1]], b0 + #2[[1]], #1[[2]] - 1} &, 
    Partition[{a, b1}, 2, 1]]]

sum[f_, LessEqual[b0_, a__, b1_]] := Sum[f, ##] & @@ 
  Reverse[MapThread[{#1, b0, #2} &, {{a}, Rest[{a, b1}]}]]

sum[f_, (ii : HoldPattern[Inequality[PatternSequence[_, 
   (Less | LessEqual)] .., _]])] := 
  Module[{lst, ops, vars, b0, b1, count},
   lst = List @@ ii;
   ops = lst[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]] /. {Less -> 1, LessEqual -> 0};
   vars = lst[[;; -1 ;; 2]];
   Sum[f, ##] & @@ 
     Reverse[MapThread[{#1[[1]], lst[[1]] + #2, #1[[2]] - #3} &, 
       {Partition[Rest[vars], 2, 1], Accumulate[Most[ops]], Rest[ops]}
     ]
  ]]
```

So for example

```
sum[f[a, b, c], 0 < a <= b < c < d] // TraditionalForm
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Neater and more flexible than my hack! Dealing with the different inequality forms is annoying (I had similar issues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6806152/421225)). It would be better if Mma made `Less` and `LessEqual` act as shorthand for the various `Inequality[]` constructions...

Answer (score 9):

I will tackle the sum explicitly mentioned in your post.

Suppose you use `i[1]`, `i[2]` and so on for iteration variables. The product can be formed as 
follows. `-Subsets[Array[i, n], {2}]` will form pairs. $i_s-i_r$ for $1\leqslant r<s\leqslant n$.

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := Block[{i},
 Sum[Apply[Times, -Subtract @@@ Subsets[Array[i, n], {2}]], ##] & @@ 
  Reverse@Partition[Array[i, n + 1, 1] /. {i[n + 1] -> 2 n + 1}, 2, 1]]
```

The sequence $f_n$ grows rather fast:

```
In[79]:= {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]}

Out[79]= {3, 20, 588, 114048, 194347296, 3634840535040}
```

Comment: Does your function generate all the summands in memory or does it generate and sum them sequentially?

Comment: It generates them _sequentially_. This what `Sum` does for small enough explicit bounds. You can enforce this to always be the case for explicit integer limits with `Method -> "Procedural"` as documented on `Sum`'s [reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it

```
i[0]=0;
T[n_]:=Table[{i[k],i[k-1]+1,2n+1},{k,1,n}];
f[n_]:=Sum[Product[i[s]-i[r],{r,1,n},{s,r+1,n}],Evaluate[Sequence@@T[n]]];
```

Comment: Yes, the use of `Evaluate` and `Sequence` is the key.