# Constructing a Summation with a Variable Number of Inner Sums

Tags: syntax

I have a question regarding multiple sums. And my second index depends on the first index. Here it is:

$$
\sum_{d=1}^{P}e^{-d}\sum_{\substack{1\leq k_{1}\leq Q \\ 1\leq k_{2}\leq Q \\... \\...\\1\leq k_{d}\leq Q}}e^{-(k_{1}+...+k_{d})}
$$

I could not write this sum in mathematica. The problem is that my second sum is a multiple sum and I do not know how to sum $d$ times. How can I do it?

Comment: See answers to this question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134/sum-over-n-variables

Answer (score 8):

Let's concentrate on the inner multiple sum. First note that we know `d` because it is given from the outer sum. If we want to write the expression 
$$-\exp\left[k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_d\right]$$
in *Mathematica* we could do this very easy. First we create the list `{k[1],k[2],...,k[d]}` and remember, that this is internally nothing more than `List[k[1],k[2],...,k[d]]`. If we would now replace the `List` head with `Plus`, then it is exactly what we want. For this we can use `Apply` which is written `@@` in infix notation. That leaves how to create the `{k[1],k[2],...,k[d]}` list. Here we can use `Table` or `Array` *or* we think of it as _mapping the function `k` over the list `{1,2,...,d}`. This can be written as

```
k /@ Range[d]
```

for a known `d`. All together this gives

```
Exp[-Plus @@ k /@ Range[d]]
```

Now we need to build a multiple `Sum`, summing over `d` different `k`. Again, this can be done in several ways. One way is to create a function which gets as arguments the indices for a `Sum`

```
f = Function[Sum[1, ##]]
```

I only use 1 in the sum for the sake of simplicity.
You may ask now, what this `##` is: it's the sequence of all arguments given to f.  So lets try it:

```
In[63]:= {Sum[1, {3}], f[{3}]}

Out[63]= {3, 3}

In[62]:= {Sum[1, {3}, {5}], f[{3}, {5}]}

Out[62]= {15, 15}
```

Seems to work. The only think which is left now, is to create the ranges `{k[i],1,q}` where `i` is always a concrete number. Here we can use again the trick with `Range` and for a known `d` this gives a list of ranges:

```
{k[#], 1, q} & /@ Range[d] 

(* For d = 3 for instance
Out[64]= {{k[1], 1, q}, {k[2], 1, q}, {k[3], 1, q}}
*)
```

The last thing is to think about, that our `Sum` function needs a `Sequence` of arguments and the above is a `List`. But we already solved the problem of replacing the `List` with something different by using `@@`. This gives all together:

```
Sum[Exp[-Plus @@ k /@ Range[d]], ##] & @@ ({k[#], 1, q} & /@ Range[d])
```

Don't be afraid of the expression, because now you know every single piece of it and you know what every piece does. You could try it by for instance

```
With[{d = 4},
 Sum[Exp[-Plus @@ k /@ Range[d]], ##] & @@ ({k[#], 1, q} & /@ Range[d])
 ]
```

and get $$\frac{e^{-4 q} \left(e^q-1\right)^4}{(e-1)^4}$$ or you use this to plant it directly into your outer sum

```
mysum[p_Integer] := 
 Sum[Exp[-d]*
     Sum[Exp[-Plus @@ k /@ Range[d]], ##] & @@ ({k[#], 1, q} & /@ 
     Range[d]), {d, 1, p}]
```

I put it into a function `mysum`, because `p` needs to be a number to make all the `Range`s work. Now you should check `mysum[2]`

$$\frac{e^{-2 q-2} \left(e^q-1\right)^2}{(e-1)^2}+\frac{e^{-q-1}
   \left(e^q-1\right)}{e-1}$$

Comment: How do you get $2(q^5 + q^4)$? I don't get that result with your code.

Comment: Me neither. Wherever I copied this from.. it was the wrong place. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: I do not understand why mathematica doesnt give the closed expression for mysum. because it seems that mysum[n] gives $x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n$ where $x$ is mysum[1]

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure there's a way to do this symbolically, but you can do the following:

```
multipleSum[P_] := 
 Sum[Exp[-d] Sum[
    Exp[-Plus @@ Table[Symbol["k" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, d}]], 
    Evaluate[
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[{Symbol["k" <> ToString[i]], 1, Q}, {i, 1, d}]]], {d, 1, 
   P}]
```

For example:

```
In[87]:= multipleSum[3]

Out[87]= (E^(-1 - Q) (-1 + E^Q))/(-1 + E) + (
 E^(-2 - 2 Q) (-1 + E^Q)^2)/(-1 + E)^2 + (
 E^(-3 - 3 Q) (-1 + E^Q)^3)/(-1 + E)^3
```

I *think* this is correct.

Comment: I think you missed a minus-sign in the inside exponential.

Comment: @halirutan erk, thanks: fixed