# Generating a list of symbolic coefficients

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions

I am trying to do something which I assume should be very simple: I want to generate a list with symbolic coefficients that looks like this:

```
A = {a0, a1, a2, a3, ... , a20};
```

And I mean to do this a lot up to an arbitrary number, so I wouldn't want to type them all. So of course when I set one of them, say `a1 = 5`, then it should be updated in the list, so now:

```
A = {a0, 5, a2, a3, ... , a20};
```

I might just be missing an obvious *Mathematica* command here that does this... Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: You can use `Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[20]`.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly the line that I needed! (except that I used `Range[0,20]` as I start at 0, but never mind that)

Comment: Other possible duplicates: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5056/57)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the problem you are having, it is maybe enough when you create a list of `{a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], ...}`. This can be done with

```
Array[a, 10]
```

or, if you like `Table`

```
Table[a[i], {i, 10}]
```

If you really want to create `an` where `n` is a number, then you can use `Symbol` to convert a string to a *symbol*

```
Table[Symbol["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 10}]
```

or, if you want definitely unassigned variables and you don't care which numbers they get

```
Table[Unique["a"], {10}]
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! The `Symbol[]` command was just what I needed!

Comment: What about also mentioning `ToExpression`?

Comment: @YvesKlett I assume it will be closed as dup soon and in the other post `ToExpression` is used.

Comment: Yup. I voted for that but I think your answer is nice, short and useful anyway.