# Using Table with arbitrary number of variables

Tags: syntax, string-manipulation

Let $P=\{p_1,...p_n\}$. I would like a way to implent
Table[Expression,{$p_1$,lim},{$p_2$,lim},...,{$p_n$,lim}] where n and lim are parameters defined by the user. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide minimal example?

Comment: This seems very familiar, assuming my interpretation is correct, but I can't find the original.  Help, anyone?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I agree it seems familiar.  This is the closest I've found: [5056](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5056/)

Comment: This question was closed and due for deletion.  I feel that it could be useful as a redirect so I am marking it as a duplicate instead, even though the "original" is about `Sum` rather than `Table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner:

```
Table[expr,Evaluate[Sequence@@({#,lim}&/@Array[Subscript[p, #] &, n])]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
p0 = Array[Subscript[p, #] &, 7]  
l0 = Table[1 + Mod[i, 3], {i, 7}]  
Table[q, Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[{p0, l0}]]]
```