# How would one minimize with respect to an unknown number of variables?

Tags: syntax, summation

Say I had a function like the following:

```
f[n_] := Sum[a + Subscript[b, k], {k, 0, n}]
```

Such that `f[5] == 6 a + Subscript[b, 0] + Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[b, 2] + Subscript[b, 3] + Subscript[b, 4] + Subscript[b, 5]`

How would I go about minimizing `f` with respect to both a and all of the subscripted bs? How would I go about minimizing `f[5]` without manually supplying `{a, Subscript[b, 0], Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2], Subscript[b, 3], Subscript[b, 4], Subscript[b, 5]}` as the vars param?

I'm asking about a specific simplified case here, but hopefully answers will be applicable in the general case and to other functions that take a vars param other than Minimize[]

Comment: did you look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5056/16), [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134/16) or any of the other similar questions around this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this has been answered many times, let me answer it once more:

```
varnum = 10;
vars = Symbol["a" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[varnum];
of = Total[-vars^2 + vars^4];
Minimize[of, vars]
```

[image]

Comment: It would be more straightforward to define vars by vars = Array[a,  varnum]

Comment: @BobHanlon Perhaps, but I wanted them to be symbols